# Is there and efficient method to get UserProfile from email in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: search, user-profile, active-directory

I need to find user-profile using the active directory email account.

Note: its not the 'work-email' but the email in AD.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms458648.aspx) can do this - but I can't guarantee that it'll be *fast*.

It should be something like:

```
SPPrincipcalInfo user = SPUtility.ResolvePrincipal( webApp, null, "email", SPPrincipalType.User, SPPrincipalSource.Windows, true);
UserProfileManager profileManager = new UserProfileManager(serviceContext);
if (profileManager.UserExists(user.LoginName))
{
    UserProfile userProfile = profileManager.GetUserProfile(user.LoginName);
}
```

In this "email" would be your email string. It definitely works, but I have has some issues with speed. It's worth testing.

Comment: I get the following Error:: **No Overload for the method ResolvePrincipal takes 5 arguments**

Comment: Oops, yes, forgot the second parameter, which can be null - updated example.